# Error when upload any file using the Responsive Filemanager

Tags: javascript, ckeditor4.x, responsive-filemanager

I am getting the following error when I upload any file using the responsive filemanager lastupdate

Error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

[image]

I following the [documentation](https://www.responsivefilemanager.com/index.php#documentation-section) for ckeditor

I appreciate any help

Thank you

Comment: Please add some of your code, and folks will be more than happy to help.

Comment: I just downloaded the files from [link]https://www.responsivefilemanager.com/index.php#download-section I uploaded it to the webserver and when I try to upload any file using this script show the error  SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60552341/14011923 This answer is the solution, I hope it works for you

Answer (score 3):

UploadHandler.php change line: 1431 and 496 to

```
$uploaded_bytes = $this->fix_integer_overflow((int)(isset($content_range[1]) ? $content_range[1]: 1));
```

This works for me!